# Angularjs function inside foreach loop not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm, graph

I have two functions `deleteNode`, which accepts a node id and `deleteEdge` ,which takes a edge object as input.`deleteEdge` is triggered when a button is pressed and it deletes a particular node and also deletes all its connected edges. However my code only seems to delete the first edge that was added in the array.Not sure what is causing this problem.

Here $scope.nodes is an array of objects with each object looks like this:

```
var node = {
    id:$scope.node_id,
    Yedges_id:[],
    Nedges_id:[],
}
```

And $scope.edges is an array of objects where each edge looks like :

```
var edge = {
    id: $scope.edge_id,
    start_id: start,
    end_id: end,
}
```

```
     $scope.deleteEdge = function(edge){
        var index = $scope.edges.indexOf(edge)
        var start_idx = $scope.nodes.findIndex(node=>node!==undefined && node.id==edge.start_id);
        var end_idx = $scope.nodes.findIndex(node=>node!==undefined && node.id==edge.end_id);
        var Ystart_edge_idx = $scope.nodes[start_idx].Yedges_id.indexOf(edge.id);
        var Nstart_edge_idx = $scope.nodes[start_idx].Nedges_id.indexOf(edge.id);
        var end_edge_idx = $scope.nodes[end_idx].Yedges_id.indexOf(edge.id);
        if(Ystart_edge_idx!==-1){
            $scope.nodes[start_idx].Yedges_id.splice(Ystart_edge_idx,1);
        }
        if(Nstart_edge_idx!==-1){
            $scope.nodes[start_idx].Nedges_id.splice(Nstart_edge_idx,1);
        }
        $scope.nodes[end_idx].Yedges_id.splice(end_edge_idx,1);
        $scope.edges.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

```
    $scope.deleteNode = function(id){
        var index = $scope.nodes.findIndex(x=>x!==undefined && x.id===id);
        $scope.nodes[index].Yedges_id.forEach(edge_id => {
            var edge = $scope.edges.filter(edge=>edge.id==edge_id)
            $scope.deleteEdge(edge[0]);
        });
        $scope.nodes[index].Nedges_id.forEach(edge_id => {
            var edge = $scope.edges.filter(edge=>edge.id==edge_id)
            $scope.deleteEdge(edge[0]);
        });
        delete $scope.nodes[index]
    }
```

Comment: Consider using `filter()` to return a  new array?

Comment: I have tried this but still, it is not working. @charlietfl

Comment: No need to do a delete with a filtered array if you just reassign the new array to the property that contained the original